# How to save API output to a table in a html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get the output (room_presences.occupied) from my API request and save that as field in the Occupied column for the table in the html page. How do I save the API request output and add that to the table?

For some context, it's a room occupancy detection system. I'm trying to save the occupancy status for the rooms into a table which is displayed on the html page (below) in the occupancy column. I have it displaying to console to show the request works.

```
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/api/room_presences', true);

request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

  data.forEach(room_presences => {
  // Log each Occupancy
    console.log(room_presences.occupied);
  });
}

// Send request
request.send();
```

Comment: use a template to turn json into html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, here is a solution, the gist of it:

```
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/api/room_presences", true);

request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
  // have a dom node that would contain the table
  const tableContainerEl = document.querySelector("#table_id")
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // skip the header row with +1
    const rowIndex = i + 1;
    const row = tableContainerEl.rows[rowIndex];
    // we hit an empty row,
    // so there is probably no more rows with content
    // get out of the loop
    if (!row) {
      break;
    }

    const bookedCellIndex = 1;
    const bookedCell = row.cells[1];
    bookedCell.innerHTML = data[i].occupied ? "YES" : "NO";
    const occupancyCellIndex = 4;
    const occupancyCell = row.cells[occupancyCellIndex];
    occupancyCell.innerHTML = data[i].occupied;
  }
};

// Send request
request.send();
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution, however I'm getting this error "script_occupancy.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". I have edited my original post to show the html code with the table. Would you be able to show me how to connect it to that table?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.